# Font-Stack won't load using toggleClass() or .css() jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am building a page for people with disabilities that involves demonstrating several fonts. There will be a pane with buttons that either a) call different classes that will load the environment, or call the jquery .css() function to load the environment that way.

I have gotten both methods to work--for everything except the font-family. I've put the font-stacks into the classes, loaded the classes, and everything but font-family works. I've also loaded everything into a .css() statement--and everything but font-family works.  What appears on the page appears to be the default serif browser font.  I can resize it, color it, or anything else.  What I can’t do is change it to another font.

Right now I’m trying switching web-safe fonts.

Here's the jQuery I'm using now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#numone").click(function(){
$("#texdiv").toggleClass("graybkd");
$("#texdiv").html("Here the text is blue on a Gray Background. Does this feel better? This font should be  sans-serif, which is easier for vision-impaired people to read..."); 

}); 
});
```

When try this with the .css(), the toggleClass statement is commented out and after the event handler the code looks like this:

```
$("#texdiv").css({"font-family" : "Tahoma", "background-color" : "#dddddd", "border-color" : "#0000dd"}); ---   etc.
```

If you want to see how this all works, you can check the following jsfiddle.net page:  http://jsfiddle.net/gershonb/eJapD/118/

Could it be that even web-safe fonts have to be prefetched somehow?  The page will be using some specialty fonts that I know will have to be prefetched, but Tahoma should give you a nice sans-serif look.

It kind of stumps me when everything works except for one small part.

Thanks

Gershon

Comment: Have you thouhgt of css? So you can use your classes to define a custom font? google `font converter` or something. Or are you bound to this jquery mistake? http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 0):

If I replace your .toggleClass() with the .css() in your fiddle is works just fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/eJapD/143/

I also created a demo fiddle that changes font-family using css() here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/iGanja/3yqpg/

```
<h2>This is Text</h2>

<button id="tahoma">Tahoma</button>
<button id="arial">Arial</button>
<button id="verdana">Verdana</button>
<button id="times">Times New Roman</button>
<button id="courier">Courier</button>

<script>
   $("#tahoma").on("click", function() {$("h2").css({"font-family":"Tahoma"}); });
   $("#arial").on("click", function() {$("h2").css({"font-family":"Arial"}); });
   $("#verdana").on("click", function() {$("h2").css({"font-family":"Verdana"}); });
   $("#times").on("click", function() {$("h2").css({"font-family":"Times New Roman"}); });
   $("#courier").on("click", function() {$("h2").css({"font-family":"Courier"}); });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, thanks everyone.  This was a case of tunnel vision on my part.  I'm so addicted to Firefox and Firebug that I forgot to check this in Chrome, where it indeed works fine.  It turns out that in researching my site I had left an option unchecked in Firefox that should have been: "Allow pages to use their own fonts." Once I checked that, the code worked.